# Selecting the required fields from JSON in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

Below is the JSON data that i have and i am trying to get only name , after_count .

```
{
    "total_count": 125,
    "limit": 100,
    "operatingsystems": [
        {
            "category": null,
            "name": "abc",
            "total_count": 1,
            "notes": "",
            "after_count": 11,
            "id": 1,
            "aliases": []
        },
        {
            "category": null,
            "name": "cdef",
            "total_count": 2,
            "notes": "",
            "after_count": 62,
            "id": 2,
            "aliases": []
        },
```

My code:

```
data = [item for item in objects if item["after_count"] >= 0]
```

Output i am getting:

```
"
a
l
i
a
s
e
s
"
:

[
]
```

Can someone please guide me in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I added a couple of characters to the string in your question, so that the syntax of the json would be complete, then stuffed it into `json.loads` to create a json object.

```
s = '''{
    "total_count": 125,
    "limit": 100,
    "operatingsystems": [
        {
            "category": null,
            "name": "abc",
            "total_count": 1,
            "notes": "",
            "after_count": 11,
            "id": 1,
            "aliases": []
        },
        {
            "category": null,
            "name": "cdef",
            "total_count": 2,
            "notes": "",
            "after_count": 62,
            "id": 2,
            "aliases": []
        }]}'''

import json

j = json.loads(s)

print (j["operatingsystems"][0]["name"])
print (j["operatingsystems"][0]["after_count"])
print (j["operatingsystems"][1]["name"])
print (j["operatingsystems"][1]["after_count"])
```

The final four statements show how to access the items you want.